# Cannot link against Lua 5.3.4 using CMake on Windows: Could NOT find Lua (missing: LUA_LIBRARIES) (found version "5.3.4")

Tags: c++, lua, cmake

I'm not understanding how to use CMake (3.11) to locate the dynamic version of Lua 5.3.4 on Windows using VS 2017. I set up `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to point to a directory with `include\lua.h` and `lib\lua53.dll`. These are the relevant lines in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
if(NOT DEFINED LUA_INCLUDE_DIR OR NOT DEFINED LUA_LIBRARIES)
    find_package(lua REQUIRED)
endif()
include_directories(${LUA_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LUA_LIBRARIES})
```

When trying to run `cmake . -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"` I get this error:

```
Could NOT find Lua (missing: LUA_LIBRARIES) (found version "5.3.4")
```

The script says that the library version was found at the path I gave it, but doesn't find the library file, which is named `lua53.dll`. Looking at the source of `FindLua.cmake` it seems like this would match one of the name matchers for major and minor version.

```
set(_lua_library_names
    lua${LUA_VERSION_MAJOR}${LUA_VERSION_MINOR}
    lua${LUA_VERSION_MAJOR}.${LUA_VERSION_MINOR}
    lua-${LUA_VERSION_MAJOR}.${LUA_VERSION_MINOR}
    lua.${LUA_VERSION_MAJOR}.${LUA_VERSION_MINOR}
)
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: CMake wants `.lib` file, which contains list of symbols, exported by `.dll` file. Exactly this file (not `.dll` one) is needed for linking. Make sure that your have `.lib` file for Lua.

Comment: Tried that and it ends up finding the library, but now I get various errors complaining about unresolved externals at link time like `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol lua_toboolean`.

Comment: Never mind, it was the wrong library type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out I needed the static version of Lua 5.3.4 (`lua53.lib`) only. Putting that in the prefix instead allows Lua to be detected. For VS 2017 the appropriate download from `luabinaries` is `lua-5.3.4_Win64_vc14_lib.zip`.